# Expresión regular MySQL para que contenga exactamente 2 asteriscos

Tags: mysql, regex

Necesito hacer 2 consultas así:

Tengo una lista de códigos donde algunos contienen 1 asterisco y otros contienen 2 asteriscos. Un código de 1 asterisco es "hermano de otros que contengan 2 asteriscos" (empiezan con el mismo código, solo los diferencia la terminación).

```
045PLANO*7040
045PLANO*7040*1

045REDOND*14748
045REDOND*14748*1
045REDOND*14748*2
```

Necesito hacer 2 consultas que luego relacionaré:

1. una que me muestre las referencias que tienen 1 solo asterisco, y
2. otra que me muestre las que tienen 2 asteriscos.

Consulta 1

```
045PLANO*7040
045REDOND*14748
```

Consulta 2

```
045PLANO*7040*1
045REDOND*14748*1
045REDOND*14748*2
```

La regla general para la consulta de 2 asteriscos sería: que comience por cualquier valor, contenga 1 asterisco, continúe con cualquier valor, contenga 1 asterisco, termine por cualquier valor.

Intenté con esto, pero no me funciona:

```sql
select referenciaProducto
  from Producto 
 where codigoAlternoProducto like 'ONG*%' 
   and referenciaProducto REGEXP '^.*[.*.].*[.*.].*$'
 order by referenciaProducto;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que coincida si y sólo si tiene 1 asterisco:

```
campo REGEXP '^[^*]*\\*[^*]*$'
```

Para que coincida si y sólo si tiene 2 asteriscos:

```
campo REGEXP '^[^*]*(\\*[^*]*){2}$'
```

[<kbd>Demo en SQLfiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaf438/6/0)

**Descripción**

- `^` Coincide con el inicio del texto.
- `[^*]*` Cualquier número de caracteres que no sean asteriscos.
- `(\\*[^*]*){2}` Es un grupo que se repite 2 veces, que coincide con:

  - `\\*` Un asterisco literal.
  - `[^*]*` Cualquier número de caracteres que no sean asteriscos.
- `$` El fin del texto.

[image: Demo en Debuggex]